# HTML Graphics - HTML Game: Collusion control (destroy and score)

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I was putting in practice the HTML Game for the first time. 
I managed to get through with my game just having the https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/game_intro.asp as my only guide. 
The game is very simple: Random objects (green squares) fall from above. The player (red square) moves right and left. The main goal here in the game is for the player to collect/collide with as many as falling objects. Every time the collision happens with 1 object, the player earns 1 point. 
Now, how can i destroy the object(green square) that collides with the player and set 1 point at a time?

Here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Food Game v1</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<style>
canvas {
    border:1px solid #d3d3d3;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#FFFDF0, white);
}

  /* buttons align in center*/
  .center {
  margin: auto;
  width: 90%;
  padding: 10px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body onload="startGame()">
<script>

var myGamePiece;
var myFallenObj_ = []; //array of fallen objects
var myScore;

function startGame() {
  myGamePiece = new component(30, 30, "red", 130, 300);
  myScore = new component("10px", "Consolas", "black", 100, 345,"text");
  myGameArea.start();
}

var myGameArea = {
    canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
    start : function() {
        this.canvas.width = 300;
        this.canvas.height = 350;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
        this.frameNo = 0; //if we use an array
        this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
    },
    clear : function() {
        this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    },
    stop: function(){
        clearInterval(this.interval);
    }
}

function component(width, height, color, x, y, type) {
    this.type = type;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.score = 0;
    this.speedX = 0;
    this.speedY = 0;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.update = function() {
        ctx = myGameArea.context;
        if(this.type == "text"){ //check on text object
          ctx.font = this.width + " " + this.height;
          ctx.fillStyle = color;
          ctx.fillText(this.text, this.x, this.y);
        }else {
          ctx.fillStyle = color;
          ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
        }
    }
    this.newPos = function() {
        this.x += this.speedX;
        this.y += this.speedY;
    }
    this.crashWith = function(otherobj){
        var myleft = this.x;
        var myright = this.x + (this.width);
        var mytop = this.y;
        var mybottom = this.y + (this.height);
        var otherleft = otherobj.x;
        var otherright = otherobj.x + (otherobj.width);
        var othertop = otherobj.y;
        var otherbottom = otherobj.y + (otherobj.height);
        var crash = true;
        if((myright < otherleft) || (myleft > otherright) || (mybottom < othertop) || (mytop > otherbottom)) {
            crash = false;
        }
        return crash;
    }
}

function updateGameArea() {
    myGameArea.clear();
    myGamePiece.newPos();
    myGamePiece.update();
    var width_, minWidth_, maxWidth_;
    var x,y;
    
    for (i=0;i<myFallenObj_.length; i++){
      if(myGamePiece.crashWith(myFallenObj_[i])){ //if collision happens
        myScore.score ++;
        //destroy(myFallenObj_[i]);
      }
    }

    myScore.text = "SCORE: " + myScore.score;
    //check myGamePiece not go over the left border
    if(myGamePiece.x <= 0)
      myGamePiece.x = 1;
    //check myGamePiece not go over the right border
    if(myGamePiece.x > 265)
      myGamePiece.x = 260;

    myScore.update();

    myGameArea.frameNo +=1;
    if (myGameArea.frameNo == 1 || everyinterval(150)){
      //x = 10;
      minWidth_=0;
      maxWidth_=300;
      width_ = Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxWidth_-minWidth_+1)+minWidth_);
      y = - 50;
      myFallenObj_.push(new component (30,30,"green", width_, y));
    }
    for (i=0; i<myFallenObj_.length; i++){
      myFallenObj_[i].x +=0;
      myFallenObj_[i].y +=1;
      myFallenObj_[i].update();
    }
   
}

function everyinterval(n){
  if((myGameArea.frameNo /n) % 1 == 0)
    return true;
  return false;
}

function moveleft() {
    myGamePiece.speedX = - 2;

}

function moveright() {
    myGamePiece.speedX = 2;

}

function clearmove() {
    myGamePiece.speedX = 0;
    myGamePiece.speedY = 0;
}
</script>
<div class="center">

  <button onmousedown="moveleft()" onmouseup="clearmove()" ontouchstart="moveleft()">LEFT</button>
  <button onmousedown="moveright()" onmouseup="clearmove()" ontouchstart="moveright()">RIGHT</button><br><br>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

What i've done so far is to apply that collision and count the score, but the score counts for as long as the red and green keep touching themselves repeatedly (which is wrong).

Any suggestions are more than welcome, thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `scorable` attribute to your `component`:

```
function component(...) {
...
this.scorable = true;
...
}
```

Then use the attribute to flag if it still `scorable`, if not skip:

```
for (i=0;i<myFallenObj_.length; i++){
  if(myGamePiece.crashWith(myFallenObj_[i]) && myFallenObj_[i].scorable){ //if collision happens
    myScore.score ++;

    myFallenObj_[i].scorable = false;
    //destroy(myFallenObj_[i]);
  } 
}
```

Comment: Hi @ACD and thank you for pointing out the flags (quite useful!)
I tried ur example but didn't work. I also tried something like: 

var scorable = true;
    
    for (i=0;i<myFallenObj_.length; i++){
      if(myGamePiece.crashWith(myFallenObj_[i]) && scorable == true){ 
          myScore.score ++;
          scorable = false;
          }
      }
Still no results

Comment: @BrainWash have you already added the attribute to the object? like how you add `x` and `y` attribute to it? you have to set it to `true` by default for it to work

Comment: Can you explain the above with an example? You got me confused with the x and y attributes. Tbh, i didn't know any scrorable attribute ever existed. Thx

Comment: @BrainWash I've updated the answer. To make it more clear: you have to update your "component " constructor and add flag attribute `scorable` and set it to `true` by default. You then have to use this attribute while checking for collision if it is still scorable then do the scoring and stuff and set the `scorable` flag to false, by this, on the next scene update, the object that is `scorable = false` will skip the process.

Comment: Additional optimization if you check if the object is still scorable before checking collision to skip the collision detection algorithm if its no longer scorable.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @ACD i solved half of my problem concerning the points' count.
The other half of my answer was how to handle my (green) component: get the point when the green component crashes on to the red one and then disappears. 
Well, i couldn't handle properly the destroy attribute of my object (in this case my component). Too much JS with Unity, i suppose :p .  I don't know if there is such an attribute for the HTML Canvas' philosophy. To "apply" in a way the destroy attribute to my problem here (as to make my green component to disappear from the canvas) i had to create an "illusion" that came to my mind at first. Basically, playing with the component's positioning around the canvas. 
Mainly, i had to set a variable `var garbagePOS = 2000;` //any possible measure out of my canvas size. 
And then i set the position x of my crashed green component into its new positioning equals 2000 (visually, out of my content) `myFallenObj_[i].x = garbagePOS;` And just like that it creates the illusion. Probably, not an ideal solution. However it works fine for me at the moment.  Any more suggestions for the above?